# Argument of type '(props: ITableProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type ... - React HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hoc

I have a loader HOC

HOC:

```
const withLoader = <P extends object>(WrappedComponent: new () => React.Component<P, any>, loading: boolean) => {

    return class WithLoading extends React.Component<P, any> {
        render() {

            return (
                <div >
                    <div className={`${loading} ? 'loader' : '' "></div>
                    <WrappedComponent {...this.props} /> 
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this in this way, for example:

```
const TableHOC = withLoader(Table,true);
```

Now my table or any other component for example, will have its own well defined props interface. Everything is well typed.

However I am getting this issue

```
Argument of type '(props: ITableProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => Component<object, any, any>'.
  Type '(props: ITableProps) => Element' provides no match for the signature 'new (): Component<object, any, any>'.ts(2345)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You could try using `WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>`

Comment: Thanks, It worked!!. I had tried this earlier but then I messed with passing the loading props not as a separate argument to my HOC but as a prop via the Wrapped Component.

Comment: Great! Let me add that as an answer.

Comment: I've added my thoughts as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use `React.ComponentType` for the type instead:

```
const withLoader = <P extends object>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>, loading: boolean) => {
  // ...
}
```

Just a note though, if you're planning on toggling the value of `loading` via a state change, you'll want to pass it as a prop instead. This is because every time you call `withLoader` to get an enhanced component out, it is a *new component*, meaning that if you do it inside `render`, React will always unmount and remount that rendered component. This also means that any state inside the enhanced component will be lost.

For example:

```
interface WithLoadingProps {
  loading: boolean;
}

const withLoader = <P extends object>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>
) => {
  return class WithLoading extends React.Component<P & WithLoadingProps, any> {
    render() {
      const { loading } = this.props;
      return (
        <div>
          <div className={loading ? "loader" : ""}>
            <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
};
```

Sample use:

```
const MyComponent = ({ text }: { text: string }) => {
  return <div>{text}</div>;
};
const MyLoadingComponent = withLoader(MyComponent);

class Foo extends React.Component<{}, { loading: boolean }> {
  render() {
    const { loading } = this.state;
    return <MyLoadingComponent loading={loading} text="foo" />;
  }
}
```

As a cherry on top, consider also adding the `displayName` [as instructed in React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-wrap-the-display-name-for-easy-debugging) - this will enhance your debugging experience when working with React's devtools.

With:

[image]

Without:

[image]

```
interface WithLoadingProps {
  loading: boolean;
}

const getDisplayName = <P extends object>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) =>
  Component.displayName || Component.name || "Component";

const withLoader = <P extends object>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>) => {
  class WithLoading extends React.Component<P & WithLoadingProps, any> {
    static readonly displayName = `WithLoading(${getDisplayName(WrappedComponent)})`;

    render() {
      const { loading } = this.props;
      return (
        <div>
          <div className={loading ? "loader" : ""}>
            <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  return WithLoading;
};
```

Comment: My use case is exactly what you have defined as the second part,i.e., changing value of loader. However, my code just works fine without passing it as a prop but passing it as an argument. Any thoughts on it?

Comment: @RohanAgarwal It does work, but you'll run into the issues I described in the second paragraph. Try for example wrapping a component with state. Then change that state inside the component (e.g. with a button and onClick), then change the value of `loading`. See what happens to the state.

Comment: Or maybe because I don't have any state inside my HOC, I am not facing the issue. Is my understanding correct? 
Right now, in my functional component, just before my return method, i am creating the enhanced component and using it inside my return method. the loading argument is getting updated via state changes.

Comment: @RohanAgarwal It's an antipattern to create a component inside the render function (i.e. render() or a function component). Try out the example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-cannon-b1jww?file=/src/App.tsx - Click on "add" a few times, then toggle loading.

Comment: TYSM. This is by far one of the best discussions that I had on SO :) If you could help me on one more scenario. Suppose, I am controlling my loading value not through a state but by a selector (redux). Now, if instead of passing a boolean value as a prop to my HOC, can I pass my selector name (a string) to my HOC and inside the HOC I listen to the selector and control my loading class. Is there any problem with this approach?

Comment: That works. You could even pass the selector function itself, kinda like how `connect` takes in mapStateToProps etc